# Mule MEL String comparision

Tags: mule

```
<logger message="id is===#[flowVars.fein.contains(flowVars.clientId)]===" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
<logger message="compare id is===#[flowVars.fein.contains('12-345678')]===" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

This works fine for me i.e it verifies string comparision and returns the Boolean values. Now if my input contains values with appended |,(`eg:,12-345678|22-345678|33-345678`) how do I compare it?

In Java it is : `new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s.split("\\|"))).contains(inputValues);` which will return the true/false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve but you can use the same Java expression in MEL:

```
#[Arrays.asList(flowVars.fein.split('\\|')).contains('12-345678')]
```

There's also regex and wildcard functions that can provide more complex String comparison: https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+Reference#MuleExpressionLanguageReference-wildcard

Or you can take advantage of MVELs projections and folds maybe:

```
#[($ in flowVars.fein.split("\\|")).contains(inputValues)]
```

Comment: #[Arrays.asList(flowVars.sfdcFein.split('\\|')).contains(flowVars.psiFein)] worked for me!.

Answer (score -2):

In MuleSoft you can use any java code by a component named EXPRESSION.